# In expression engine: Manipulate content of textfields/wygwam-fields?

Tags: codeigniter, expressionengine

I would like to manipulate the content of a textfield/wygwam-field in expression-engine. For example, when someone uploads an mp3-file with the file-uploading-tool, I would like to convert the link into a flash-embed that calls an mp3-flashplayer.

Another example is that whenever someone posts a link to a vimeo-video I would like to convert it into an embeded version of that video.

Comment: What does 'wygwam' stand for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create an extension that hangs on the [entry_submission_ready](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/development/extension_hooks/api/channel_entries/index.html#entry_submission_ready) hook that modifies the content in the appropriate fields prior to it being saved to the DB.

Comment: That sounds just like what I am looking for, do know of any simple applications doing this? I like examples to get me started!

Comment: sorry, all I could find was this forum post: http://expressionengine.com/forums/viewthread/169717/. No mention of add-ons that use it and it appears that it may not even work properly (yet, anyway).